# How to sent image in 'application/octet-stream' content type to Azure Cognitive Services in flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, azure-cognitive-services, flutter-http

Hi I'am trying to sent a local image using application/octet-stream' content type to Azure Cognitive Services from flutter.
I have follow the following but it seem to be missing the example. The only example is for 'application/json'

```
Future getAnalisis() async {
    final uri =
        "https://****.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.1/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories,Description&details=Landmarks";
    final respon = await http.post(
      uri,
      body: _file,
      headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '*****',
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
      },
    );
    _imageVision = serializers.deserializeWith(
        ImageVision.serializer, jsonDecode(respon.body));
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

and the `_file` is from

```
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
if (pickedFile != null) _file = File(pickedFile.path);
```

I also have tried the following but it of course error

```
   body: jsonDecode({'url' : _file.path}),
      headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '*****',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
```

and currently my error message is

```
 Invalid request body "File:
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.testRun/files/Pictures/7702e794-3a57-4a3a-a271-fd7c0964544d
4388330820207050041.jpg'".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body: _file.readAsBytesSync(),`

Comment: Thanks a lot and it also work with ```await _file.readAsBytes()``` to